# Vim window resizing

Tags: vim

I split my windows in Vim horizontally. But after I split, the new window occupies half of the original window size, I want to change this and make sure the new window occupies almost the entire old window.

Basically if I open three files using horizontal split in Vim, I should see three status bars at the bottom of the screen the third file occupying the rest of the screen. The files as I already know can be navigated through <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>+arrow keys. So if I navigate to second file now, I should see one status bar at the bottom and one status bar at the top.

Kindly let me know how to configure the same. I looked up online all I could find is options to dynamically change the size or resize, but I want static one-time config (for example, in `vimrc` or `bashrc`).

Answer (score 7):

You can type in command mode `:res[ize] +N` or `:res[ize] -N` where N is the amount in which your window will grow or shrink respectively.

Go to point 6 (Window resizing) http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/windows.html but the article has everything on windows management in VIM

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hey thanks for the info, I had seen this, But I have to do this everytime i open the file. I wanted something like a static config.

Comment: you could then add a script in .vimrc to automate it when you open vim. I'll see if I have the time and then I'll update my answer. Also, you should try @magnus proposal, that is actually what I use most frequently

Answer (score 7):

If you set the `winheight` option to 999, the current window occupies as much of the screen as possible, and all other windows occupy only one line (I have seen this called "Rolodex mode"):

```
set winheight=999
```

Comment: Yay for the "Rolodex mode"!

Comment: Thanks buddy, This works perfect, I added the config in my vimrc!! Now there is just one line between status bar for each file. I can live with it. Thanks again! Btw, I have normal vim, not rolodex, but still works fine.

Comment: The effect is called "Rolodex" because you see only one window at the time and you get a sense of "stack". There's no "Rolodex Vim".

Comment: This is probably the canonical Rolodex mode: https://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1083 but it's probably just using these settings https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Window_zooming_convenience which amounts to `:set noequalalways winminheight=0 winheight=9999 helpheight=9999` - pretty good paging in a hurry when you're short of space and / or got lots of files.

Comment: This is awesome!!!

Comment: This is awesome!!!

Answer (score 4):

You might prefer just using vim tabs, which work rather like how you described.

Try this:

```
vim -p file1 file2 file3
```

Then use :tabn and :tabp to cycle fwd and back through the tabs.

I also like this mapping in .vimrc to use ctrl-l and ctrl-h to cycle fwd and back respectively:

```
noremap <C-h> :tabp<CR>
noremap <C-l> :tabn<CR>
```

Comment: You can also use `gt` and `gT` normal mode commands to cycle through the tabs.

Answer (score 1):

Command for split window:

```
:[N]sp[lit] [++opt] [+cmd]
```

Where N is height of new window. Default is to use for half the height current window. Same thing for vertcal splitting:

```
:[N]vsp[lit] [++opt] [+cmd]
```

N is width for split window. 
And so on:
    [N]new, [N]vnew

For details read the 
    :help split

But I can't understand why you do not use buffers?